# Ionic 6 and Google Analytics: It does not log

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I want to log my app views with google analytics.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-analytics

So what i have done:

- npm install cordova-plugin-google-analytics
- npm install @ionic-native/google-analytics
- ionic cap sync

Then I created a Google Analytics ID for my new Property: 3432423 (the number is random).
The new Analytics IDs are only numbered.

I added the
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/google-analytics/ngx';
to my app.module.ts and Add "GoogleAnalytics" to the providers.

In a next step I add the code:

```
this.googleAnalytics.startTrackerWithId('3432423 ')
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Google analytics is ready now');
          this.googleAnalytics.trackView('test');
          this.googleAnalytics.trackEvent("test","t1");
          // Tracker is ready
          // You can now track pages or set additional information such as AppVersion or UserId
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('Error starting GoogleAnalytics', e));
```

to my app.component.ts.
As you can see there is a log of 'Google analytic is ready now'.

So I build my App for Android and run it with the emulator.
In my logs there is write:

```
I/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main-es2015.js - Line 130 - Msg: Google analytics is ready now
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: UniversalAnalytics1536114358, service: UniversalAnalytics, action: trackView, actionArgs: ["test","",false]
V/Capacitor/Plugin: To native (Cordova plugin): callbackId: UniversalAnalytics1536114359, service: UniversalAnalytics, action: trackEvent, actionArgs: ["test","t1","",0,false]
```

So it seems to work. But the problem is, I don't get the Views or the Event on my Google Analytics.

What could be the problem?
The Tracking ID is correct, I double-checked it.

Comment: Have you tried to run the app on the real device?

Comment: Also, have you tried to run the analytics code within the     this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {...your analytics code}) ?

Comment: @RomanA. yes I have

Comment: will try to do the second one

Comment: @RomanA. To put it in platform.ready, did not solve the problem... still no logs

Comment: How long did you wait? GA takes a while to show. It is not instant.  If you want instant use Matomo

Comment: @eDriven_Levar now more than 4 hours... still nothing

Comment: @MatheusM. you need to wait for 48-72 Hours :(   Yes GA takes that long on small and new sites. They also "guess" your traffic.  Matomo is much better choice for small apps.